# Generating a file path and trimming ".aspx"

Tags: c#, asp.net, trim

I want to generate the pages file path, then trim .aspx... I've tried the code below but this isn't working. New to the Windows world, I'm used to Linux so please be nice :D

Edit: Error for my code below is: Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '[',

but once that's fixed it keeps spitting out errors. I believe I may be just getting the fundamentals of this task wrong.

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string thepath = Page.ResolveUrl(Request.RawUrl);
    string thepath = Trim([.aspx] trimChars);
    string[] a = thepath.Split('/');
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        thepath += a[i].ToLower() + "/"; ;
    }
    Canonical.Text = "<link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"https://example.com" + thepath.ToLower() + "\" />\n";
}
}
```

Comment: `this isn't working` how isn't it working? what's the output it's giving you?

Comment: @Jaxi, sorry, I've updated the post.

Comment: `string thepath = Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Replace(".aspx", "")`?

Comment: Is routing what Gerry is looking for here?

Comment: Have a look at the methods in the `System.IO.Path` class.  Specifically `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`.  It's primary use is for the file system path names, but I believe it will work in your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[.aspx]` isn't valid and you're not trimming anything. change it to the following:

```
string thepath = Page.ResolveUrl(Request.RawUrl);
thepath = thepath.Replace(".aspx","");
```

This will do as you need, but if you have .aspx anywhere else in the string it'll replace there too. If you want just the end, you can still use `TrimEnd` but it's a bit hacky IMHO.

```
string thepath = Page.ResolveUrl(Request.RawUrl);
thepath = thepath.TrimEnd(".aspx".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: Not such a fan of the `TrimEnd` solution, if there is an a,s,p or x (or any combination) before the . they will also be trimmed. e.g. `mathematica.aspx -> mathematic`

Comment: @SBFrancies, how would you tackle it?

Comment: Depends on the constraints on your input string. If it's always going to end with .aspx I would just trim off the last 5 characters. Otherwise you will need logic (maybe very simple) to know which .aspx to remove if there could possibly be more than 1. If not then the first solution above will work perfectly well.

Comment: @SBFrancies that's why I said it's a bit hacky, but it does work